# Menú desplegable error

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

mi problema es el siguiente, cuando trato de hacer mi menú desplegable, básicamente me permite hacerlo, pero se acumula todo en uno, y no permite ver las demás, no sé como solucionar eso.

Esto es lo que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería mostrarme esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero arriba del todo, intenté hacerlo con z.index, inclusive, elevándolo al 999 pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente

https://codepen.io/padr-n-rocha/pen/WWpJvV

Bueno, precisamente el problema radica en que no se posiciona correctamente los bloques como deberían

Comment: Tu link envia a una direccion vacia, prueba usando el snipet del editor de texto de aqui.

Comment: https://codepen.io/padr-n-rocha/pen/WWpJvV ya lo corregí

Comment: pero el link que pusiste se mira bien

Comment: No estoy seguro, si no estoy entendiendo tu problema, o en el codepen que dejaste funciona perfecto..

Comment: Es que al dar click sí se despliega pero el asunto es que lo tiene que hacer arriba del todo, cuando le pondo position absolute es que se aplasta todo.

Comment: Se debe de ver como la segunda imagen sí, pero no tiene que ampliar el ancho del navbar, debe de estar sobre todo eso

Comment: Solo aplica el `position: absolute` a la clase `.dropdown`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estas declarando la propiedad `position: absolute` en el elemento `.row` del `dropdown`:

```
header .usuario .dropdown .row {
    /* position:absolute; */
 }
```

Esto apunta a todos los elementos hijos dentro del menu, y al tener todos posicion absoluta, se colocan uno encima del otro; simplemente basta con mover esta propiedad al elemento `.dropdown` como tal para que sea el cajon entero el que se posicione de manera absoluta

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #141938;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #BB1F35;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.contenedor {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.izquierda {
  float: left;
}

.derecha {
  float: right;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.halfUp {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.spaceDown {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/* --- Header ---*/

header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4b0082;
}

header .contenedor {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  max-width: 300px;
}

header .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

header .logo a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .buscar {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

header .buscar input[type="text"] {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  padding-right: 32px;
}

header .buscar input[type="text"]:hover,
header .buscar input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

header .buscar .icono {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

header .buscar .icono:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

header .contacto,
header .usuario {
  display: inline-block;
}

header .contacto ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header .contacto ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 70px;
}

header .contacto ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .contacto ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .contacto ul li a .icono {
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/************* AQUI LA NUEVA PROPIEDAD*********************/

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}


/**********************************************************/

header .usuario .dropdown .row {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #888888;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .usuario .row .text {
  font-size: 16px;
}

header .usuario .row .icon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .usuario .panel :hover {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .usuario input#toggle {
  display: none;
}

header .usuario input#toggle~.dropdown {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}

header .usuario input#toggle:checked~.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

header .usuario .dropdown {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

header .usuario .dropdown .arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #f8f8f8;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

header .usuario .dropdown .row {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: left;
}

header .usuario .dropdown .row:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

header .usuario .dropdown .row:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

header .usuario .dropdown:hover>.row {
  color: #bebebe;
}

header .usuario .dropdown .row:hover {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: #6c6c6c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=yykc751rqk9e1w78c0pzk31233fnstxsrt2j79ji3qbp553n"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea'
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="logo izquierda">
        <p>
          <a href="#">Proyecto ADMUS</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="derecha">
        <form name="busqueda" class="buscar" action="buscar.php" method="get">
          <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar"><button type="submit" class="icono fa fa-search"></button>
        </form>
        <nav class="contacto">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="usuario">
          <div class="panel">
            <label class="text" for="toggle">Master Web</label>&nbsp;
            <label class="icon fas fa-angle-down" for="toggle"></label>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="arrow"></div>

            <a href="#" class="row">
              <div class="text">Edit User</div>
              <i class="icon fas fa-user"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="row">
              <div class="text">Recents Comments</div>
              <i class="icon far fa-comment-alt"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="row">
              <div class="text">favorites</div>
              <i class="icon fas fa-heart"></i>
              <!--i class="fas fa-hand-holding-heart"></i!-->
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="row">
              <div class="text">Log out</div>
              <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="row">
              <div class="text">Admin Settings</div>
              <i class="icon fas fa-cog"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO, muchas gracias c: